# WatchKit Can't Import Library From Pods

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, watchkit, swifty-json

I'm adding a watch application, and I'm attempting to import a library within my WatchKit Extension that my iOS app uses (`SwiftyJSON`). I have updated my podfile as such:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'MyApp' do
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.0'
    pod 'AlamofireImage', '~> 2.0'
    pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git'
    pod "PubNub", "~> 4.1"
    pod 'Siren'
end

target 'MyAppWatch Extension' do
    pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git'
end
```

When I run the `pod install`, everything seems to behave like it should. The problem is when I'm using the import `SwiftyJSON` inside an WKInterfaceController, I get the error No such module `SwiftyJSON`. Is there another setting that I haven't set properly?

Answer (score 1):

The way I use to add `pods` to the watchOS framework with the following `podfile`:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

use_frameworks! 

platform :ios, '8.0'

link_with 'AppName'

target 'WatchName Extension' do
  platform :watchos, '2.0'
  pod 'NameOfYourPOd', '~> x.0.0'
end
```

But there is a very important point about the include of some libraries in the Watch Extension, **there are libraries that do not support `watchos` as a platform yet**. There are some good articles about how to add it manually to its `podspec` to support it.

I hope this help you